# JTree keep expanding problem

Tags: java, jtree, expand

I want to keep my jTree file expanded. I using below code to expand the jTree :

```
public void expandAll(JTree tree) {

    int row = 0;
    while (row < tree.getRowCount()) {
        tree.expandRow(row);
        row++;
    }
}
```

It works, but when I add in new file or delete file the jtree collapse back. How can keep the jTree expanded?

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `JTree` and create a `JExpandedTree` which overrides the add and delete methods to call `expandTree` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to save the expansionState into a local variable in your method and after manipulating the JTree you can reset the expansionState from your local variable.

check [here for an example](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19857.html)